# Why isn't this javascript code working?

Tags: javascript, html, width, pixel

```js
var contentObj = getElementById("content");
var widthOfContent = screen.availWidth * 0.6;
var cssContObjStr = "width:" + (screen.availWidth * 0.6) + ";";
contentObj.style = cssContObjStr;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    jdhkfahsd jksahd fklhasdk fhaskdhf kalsdhf klashdfk hasdkf haskd hfasdkjfhkjasdh fkjasdkfh asjdkhf khdskf jhaskdjh fkjasdhf kjsahd fkasbdkfbsadvn iweb fnilewalnfiwa ebnkjsdbv jdbalisd df sads da s fsd afds fasdf sadf asdf adsf asdf sdf
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've saved the javascript file as `javas.js` on my pc. However, I'm trying to set the width as 60% of the screen width in pixels. This isn't working.

How can I manage this? And please, don't say "set it to `width:60%`".

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, not on some other page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several syntax errors, here's a list of what's wrong:

- You need to call `document.getElementById()`
- `+\` isn't needed, that's an improperly formatted literal...but isn't not needed here anyway
- The `width` is a property on `style`, just set it like I have below, make sure to include `"px"` on the end.

Overall, it should just be:

```js
var contentObj = document.getElementById("content");
var widthOfContent = screen.availWidth * 0.6;
contentObj.style.width = widthOfContent + "px";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    jdhkfahsd jksahd fklhasdk fhaskdhf kalsdhf klashdfk hasdkf haskd hfasdkjfhkjasdh fkjasdkfh asjdkhf khdskf jhaskdjh fkjasdhf kjsahd fkasbdkfbsadvn iweb fnilewalnfiwa ebnkjsdbv jdbalisd df sads da s fsd afds fasdf sadf asdf adsf asdf sdf
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
var contentObj = document.getElementById("content");
var widthOfContent = screen.availWidth * 0.6;
var cssContObjStr = "width:" + (screen.availWidth * 0.6) + "%;";
contentObj.style.cssText = cssContObjStr;
```

Thanks

Comment: @DarkLightA Oops my bad! you are right it should be "px" instead of "%"